# Al interactuar cambie el estilo de una web y se almacene

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Estoy desarrollando una web con php , javascript , html5 y css3.
Deseo cambiar de color los  segun lo que elija el usuario en un apartado de configuracion desarrollado y que se almacenen esos cambios
Como podria hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

Bueno lo primero que puedes hacer es que en la db donde se encuentra las credenciales de tu usuario agregues una columna mas que sea preferencia, en donde o bien guardas el color o un código. Entonces cuando la persona se loguea te trae ese dato y puedes poner el color de su preferencia.
Si no tambien puedes guardar ésta preferencia en el localstorage, que es un almacenamiento local y que ayuda para éstos casos donde no son datos críticos.

Saludos